# Best way to refuse adds to the queue once the manager has been stopped

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, queue

Any ideas on the best way to block all adds once stop has been called?

Also, this is the first time I have ever used LockSupport is this the best way to handle blocking dequeue while waiting for a new queue?

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;

/**
 *
 * @author Marc D. Benstein
 */
public abstract class AbstractWorkerQueue<T> implements AutoCloseable {
    private final List<T> queue;
    private final Thread thread;

    public AbstractWorkerQueue(String threadName) {
        queue = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<T>());
        thread = new Thread(new QueueManager(), threadName);
    }

    public void offer(T item) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.add(item);
        }
        LockSupport.unpark(thread);
    }

    public void clear() {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        stop();
    }

    protected void start() {
        thread.start();
    }

    protected void stop() {
        offer(null);
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

    protected abstract void process(T item);

    private class QueueManager implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                T item = null;
                synchronized (queue) {
                    if (!(queue.isEmpty())) {
                        item = queue.remove(0);
                        if (item == null) {
                            // null dentotes end of queue
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (item != null) {
                    process(item);
                } else {
                    LockSupport.park(thread);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using park/unpark along with synchronized wins the most awkward (and most likely data-race enabled) code award easily. I do use park/unpark along w/ CAS but combining w/ synchronized is truly weird. Side note: no single List implementation in Java makes a good queue. Use ConcurrentLinkedQueue and remove all synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

first *don't silently catch InterruptedException* at least reset the flag with  `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` in that catch

second there are thread-safe queue implementations which are better tuned check the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package

and there is a possibility that a thread can add a `T` and call `unpark()` before the `QueueManager` reaches it's `park()` right after it removed the last one. you were better off `wait`ing and `notify`ing on queue inside the synchronized block

Answer (score 0):

Throw an `IllegalStateException`, maybe a subclass of that.

Comment: But where? Everything I can think would produce a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new instance volatile variable isStopped to AbstractWorkerQueue class with default value as false. Turn on the flag to true once the stop method is called.

You can throw IllegalStateException on any subsequent requests of offer() or return without adding it to queue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now but how about:

```
volatile boolean closed = false;
public void offer(T item) {
    if ( !closed ) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.add(item);
            if ( item == null ) {
                closed = true; 
            }
        }
        // Not sure if this should be outside or inside the if.
        LockSupport.unpark(thread);
    }
}
```

**Added**: I think the only side effect of a race-condition here would be the possibility of a small number of extra items being posted to the queue after the null. So long as you handle that (which you seem to) in your consumer there should not be a problem. However, if that was a problem you could do:

```
volatile boolean closed = false;
public void offer(T item) {
    if ( !closed ) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            if ( !closed ) {
                queue.add(item);
                if ( item == null ) {
                    closed = true; 
                }
            }
        }
        // Not sure if this should be outside or inside the if.
        LockSupport.unpark(thread);
    }
}
```

Comment: the check `item==null` should be outside and before the synchronized block. Unpark should be outside too.

Comment: Wouldn't AtomicBoolean be better than volatile boolean?

Comment: @bestsss: I'm not sure what benefit we'd get out of moving the null check out of the `synchronized` clause but if it floats yer boat ... @initialZero Probably not, AtomicBoolean would be of value if another thread might also be trying to set `closed` to false but that is not the case here (I presume).

Comment: @Paul, you want as little contention as possible, i.e. keep your guarded blocks minimal. `closed` is unrelated to the queue (and its monitor) and it never flips back to 'false', hence no sync. needed. The code like that is still correct, though.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of your code.

---

Note offer now returns boolean like a stanard `java.util.Queue`. I prefer Throwable for close flag, even though I do not use here for anything, it's very helpful for debugging purposes to record the moment close() is invoked.
Other than that removed LinkedList and synchronized.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;

public abstract class AbstractWorkerQueue<T> {
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> queue;
    private final Thread thread;

    private volatile RuntimeException closed;//records the closure point

    public AbstractWorkerQueue(String threadName) {
        queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>();
        thread = new Thread(new QueueManager(), threadName);
    }

    public boolean offer(T item) {
        if (closed!=null)
            return false;

        queue.offer(item);      
        LockSupport.unpark(thread);
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        queue.clear();//this may not be carried properly
    }

    public void close() {
        stop();
    }

    protected void start() {
        thread.start();
    }

    protected void stop() {
        if (closed!=null)
            return;
        closed = new IllegalStateException("closure point");//should be CAS'd but meh
        LockSupport.unpark(thread);
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void process(T item);

    private class QueueManager implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (closed==null) {
                final T item = queue.poll();
                if (item != null) {
                    process(item);
                } else {
                    LockSupport.park(thread);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest you return the returned value of `queue.offer` to caller.

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue always returns true (or leads to OOM), otherwise i'd have done that.